# Batch Files If statement

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch file which I've put together, which DOES work. However, I think the coding is a bit ugly and could or possible should be done in a better way.

Essentially this file is run via a Scheduled Task daily and is designed to look inside a specific directory for a csv file with student account and credit information.

If the file is found it gets processed by the script, if not then its noted that no file was found and the script terminates.

The bit I am struggling to 'make better', is that when a csv IS found I need to discover which month we are currently in and then action dependant on that. So in this case, should the month variable return 01,02,03,04,05,06,07 or 08 then a note will be added to the processing of the file to say 'Credit Allocation 15 /16"

Alternatively, should the month be anything else (IE 09,10,11,12), then the file is processed in the same way but the note would read "Credit Allocation 16 /17"

Can anyone suggest a better coding structure for the 'If' statements in the below?

```
@echo off

::Define Variables
SET server_command="c:\Program Files\PaperCut MF\server\bin\win\server-command.exe"
SET master="c:\credit_allocation\processed\master.csv"

SET month=%date:~3,-5%

SET year=%date:~8%
SET /a sum=%date:~8%+1
echo %sum% > next_year.txt
SET /p next_year=<next_year.txt
DEL next_year.txt

SET /a sum2=%date:~8%-1
echo %sum2% > last_year.txt
SET /p last_year=<last_year.txt
DEL last_year.txt


IF EXIST "c:\credit_allocation\student_credit.csv" GOTO Do_Stuff
echo. >> %master%
echo.No CSV Found at %time:~0,5% on %date% >> %master%
GOTO EOF

:Do_Stuff

::Add run date/time to master record
echo. >> %master%
echo.Process run at %time:~0,5% on %date% >> %master%


::Find out the month, IE- Jan to Aug then still previous student year, or Sept to Dec then next student year

IF /I "%month%"=="01" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="02" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="03" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="04" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="05" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="06" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="07" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)
IF /I "%month%"=="08" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)



::Sept to Dec - Loop through CSV file for username
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (c:\credit_allocation\student_credit.csv) do (
%server_command% adjust-user-account-balance "%%a" "%%b" "Credit Allocation %year% /%next_year%"
)
GOTO Update_Master_Record


:Jan2Aug
::Jan to Aug - Loop through CSV file for username
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (c:\credit_allocation\student_credit.csv) do (
%server_command% adjust-user-account-balance "%%a" "%%b" "Credit Allocation %last_year%/%year%"
)


:Update_Master_Record
::Take contents of CSV and append to a Master CSV record then delete original CSV file
cd c:\credit_allocation
forfiles /m *.csv /c "cmd /c echo. >> %master% && type @file >> %master% && del @file"

:EOF
```

Comment: This question might suit better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick untested rewrite:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

REM Define User Variables
(SET master=c:\credit_allocation\processed\master.csv)
(SET stucred=c:\credit_allocation\student_credit.csv)
(SET srv_cmd=%ProgramFiles%\PaperCut MF\server\bin\win\server-command.exe)
(SET option=adjust-user-account-balance)

IF NOT EXIST "%student%" ((ECHO=
    ECHO=No CSV Found at %TIME:~,5% on %DATE%)>>"%master%"
    GOTO :EOF)

SET "year=%DATE:~-2%"
SET "month=1%DATE:~-7,2%"
IF %month% GTR 108 (SET/A "adj_y=(2%year%-100)-1"
    CALL SET "adj_y=%%adj_y:~-2%%/%year%") ELSE (SET/A "adj_y=(1%year%-100)+1"
    CALL SET "adj_y=0%%adj_y%%"
    CALL SET "adj_y=%year%/%%adj_y:~-2%%")

REM Add run date/time to master record
(ECHO=
    ECHO=Process run at %TIME:~,5% on %DATE%)>>"%master%"

REM Loop through CSV file for username
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=," %%I IN (%stucred%) DO (
    "%srv_cmd%" %option% "%%~a" "%%~b" "Credit Allocation %adj_y%")

REM Propagate Master CSV with contents of student CSV and delete student CSV
TYPE "%stucred%">>"%master%" && DEL "%stucred%"
```

Please do not try it on real data until it has been verified as functional

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to do this. I must admit I havent tried to run it in production, but your revision actually helped me understand how to refine my version anyway :)

What I changed was to reduce the If statements to only 1 as follows;

'IF "%month%" LSS "09" (
    GOTO Jan2Aug
)'